# Regex para subdomínios ou domínio diferente do sistema

Tags: regex

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde cada usuário terá seu subdomínio de acordo com seu login mas também irei permitir que ele configure seu próprio domínio.

Como estou desenvolvendo de forma local, também adicionei algumas regras para que tudo funcione em minha máquina local.

Para solucionar meu problema comecei a fazer um regex para caso não tenha determinadas strings ele não deixar passar mas não sei como permitir outras.

Por exemplo essa lista de domínios:

```
sistema.com.br            // não pode casar
local.dev                 // não pode casar
cliente.local.dev         // tem que casar
cliente.sistema.com.br    // tem que casar
app.sistema.com.br        // não pode casar essa
app.local.dev             // não pode casar essa
www.dominio.com.br        // regex casa, já está certo
subdominio.dominio.com.br // tem que casar
dominio.com.br            // regex casa, já está certo
```

Atualmente minha expressão regular está assim:

```
^(?!.*(sistema\.com\.br|local\.dev)).*$
```

O que eu preciso solucionar é que essa regex case com os subdomínios qualquer menos o subdomínio `app` e também não poderia casar com os domínios principais `sistema.com.br` e `local.dev`

Não estou achando uma solução já que ainda não sei como trabalhar com listas negadas junto com listas permitidas.

Resumindo o que estou tentando é casar qualquer domínio (incluindo domínios com subdomínios) menos os da lista abaixo:

```
sistema.com.br
local.dev
app.sistema.com.br
app.sistema.dev
```

Comment: fiz algo parecido recentemente e solucionei da seguinte forma. Apontei todos os domínios para o mesmo lugar físico e tratei cada domínio utilizando o php eu recebo o nome do domino que o usuário esta acessando e dou a devida tratativa com meu sistema de URL amigável.

Comment: Isso não serviria pra mim. Preciso resolver com expressão regular mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar a seguinte expressão:

```
/^((?!\b(app|sistema|local)\b)(.\w{2,3})*)(.\w{2,})(.\w{2,5})*.\w{2,3}$/igm
```

Veja funcionando com qualquer domínio: http://refiddle.com/jt2a

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O domínio teria que ser dinâmico (qualquer domínio). A ideia seria: casar qualquer domínio diferente de: sistema.com.br ou local.dev ou app.sistema.com.br ou app.local.dev. Qualquer outro domínio poderia aceitar.

Comment: Ví sua msg agora, vou atualizar... aguarda um pouco.

Comment: Atualização feita! Testa ai e me diz se ficou tudo certinho ok?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução com a seguinte expressão regular:

```
^(?!(sistema\.com\.br|app\.sistema\.com\.br|local\.dev|app\.local\.dev)).*$
```